# Rails - How to keep track of attribute names in model file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When programming `Rails` I noticed that there are no references to the attributes in a model file. By looking at a *just*-generated model file I cannot determine which attributes are contained in the model.

Do I need to look them up each time or am I missing something here?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [*annotate*](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) gem

Comment: nice! so I assume there is now official/built-in way of doing this?

Comment: Because model can handle different table structure(if needed). Actual state of model can be obtained by `MyModel.inspect` code or just `MyModel` in rails console.

Comment: That's what I mean by looking them up..

Comment: You can create two DB with same `table_name` but different structure. Then switch DB in database.yml - you'll get two different `model` in runtime. Also, you can even switch table name or schema name in runtime: `MyModel.table_name='another_table'`. So, model is NOT DB table snapshot, it's just a code for doing queries, validations and so on.